# How can I remove a text from my jlist?

Tags: java, jlist

I can add an element to my `JList`, but how can I remove an element that I selected?

Here is my code:

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Jframe.this,"Clicked?");System.out.println(n);

            String name = textfield1.getText();

            model.addElement(name);
            custList.setModel(model);
        }
    });

    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need another method that acts on the clicked method to get the id of the object and then remove it from the JList.

Comment: Maybe [`DefaultListModel#removeElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeElement-java.lang.Object-) or [DefaultListModel#`removeElementAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeElementAt-int-)?

Comment: Please make example this is importantfor me

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeElement Method to remove an object.

Here is an Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        model.addElement("1");
        model.addElement("2");
        model.addElement("3");
        System.out.println(model);//prints [1, 2, 3]
        model.removeElement("1");
        System.out.println(model);//prints [2, 3]
    }
```